# Make same thread with loop not get the same mutex again and again without sleep

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

I want to compute two things in two threads where each of them has an endless loop. Those two don't depend on each other.

Additionally I want some output on the terminal also in an endless loop (just start again each time the last output was calculated, not any step in between needed). Therefore I want some local copies of the global variables (two consecutive iterations of the first calculation and one value of the second calculation) all in a safe state.

The problem is now that I have to add some sleep to the two calculations to ever get some output from func1. I checked CPU usage and the sleep definitely lowers it.
How can I work around this?

Also see the comments for testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

int n(0);
long s(1234);
double t(56.78);

std::condition_variable cond;
std::mutex m1;
std::mutex m2;

void func1() {
    while (true) {
        // Not needed due to wait unlocking the mutex
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck1(m1);
        cond.wait(lck1);
        int n1(n);
        long s1(s);
        cond.wait(lck1);
        int n2(n);
        long s2(s);
        lck1.unlock();

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck2(m2);
        double ti(t);
        lck2.unlock();

        // calculate and print some output
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((n1*n2)/2));
        std::cout << n1 << ":" << s1 << ", " << n2 << ":" << s2 << ", " << ti << std::endl;
    }
}

void func2() {
    while (true) {
        // Why do I need this to make func1 ever proceed (ok, really seldom and random func1 got the mutex) and
        // how to work around this without sleep lowering time for computations?
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1)); // comment out to test

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck1(m1);

        n++;

        // do some stuff taking some time with s
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((n*n)/3));

        cond.notify_all();
    }
}

void func3() {
    while (true) {
        // Why do I need this to make func1 ever proceed (it got the mutex never ever) and
        // how to work around this without sleep lowering time for computations?
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1)); // comment out to test

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck2(m2);
        // do something taking some time with t
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    }
}

int main() {

    std::thread t1(func1);
    std::thread t2(func2);
    std::thread t3(func3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears you want t3 to trigger t1 and t2, and then for t1 and t2 to trigger t3. You could use 4 mutexes, m1 for t1, m2 for t2, m31 and m32 for t3. t1 waits for m1, does its work and releases m31. t1 waits for m2, does its work, and releases m32. t3 waits for m31 then m32, does its work, then releases m1 and m2.

Comment: Please post real buildable runnable code that reproduces your problem. Read about posting a [mcve].

Comment: @rcgldr The idea is nice, but it doesn't ensure that I get two consecutive values. Or maybe I just got it wrong.

Comment: @n.m. Thought I should reduce it to the bare minimum, but now changed it so it's buildable and runnable.

Comment: If you want t2 to trigger exactly one iteration of t1, this can be done with two condition variables. t2 says "hey I have incremented n" and t1 says "hey I have advanced one iteration". It is unclear what's the purpose of t3 in life. It doesn't touch any shared resources. You probably should add output statements to your example and state what output you are getting (without the sleeps) and what output you want to get.

Comment: But then t2 would wait on t1 which I don't want or at least only one time to get a consecutive value but not always. Actually I'm working with arbitrary-precision metric but that doesn't matter for the question, issue is the same. t3 only calculates some approximation of an irrational number which converges faster than t2 and I need from time to time for t1 to transform the result of t2. It doesn't matter which output, it only matters that there is an output. The problem with t2 and t3 is actually the same.

Comment: "But then t2 would wait on t1 which I don't want". It remains unclear what you do want. As it stands now, t3 does nothing visible whatsoever, and t2 increments n which is visible to t1. Do you want t1 to see every increment of n? Every tenth increment? Some increments but it doesn't matter which ones? Something else?

Comment: Simply imagine the output as (s1+s2)/t. Important is that s1 and s2 are from two consecutive iterations of t2 (n2-n1=1). Which ns these are now is totally irrelevant, it's just to get from time to time some output (simply start to compute the next one when the last completed). And t1 should block t2 and t3 as short as possible. Furthermore I think the problem is also if you only look at t1 and t3 and ignore all the stuff from t2. To break it down to one sentence it could also be: How to get to work what yield should do (but doesn't somehow) without the 1ns-sleeps?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you must assume that condition variable `wait` calls do not actually wait. A valid (though extreme) implementation is `lk.unlock(); lk.lock();`, and sometimes it does behave like that due to "spurious wakeups". You really need to associate a condition with a condition variable, and loop if the condition is not met.

Secondly, if you notify the condition variable while holding the lock on the mutex, then the waiting thread will wake from the notify, only to block on the mutex, so the notifying thread may then reacquire the mutex before the waiting thread gets a chance.

It is thus better to unlock the mutex before notifying the condition variable.

```
lck1.unlock();
cond.notify_all();
```

This gives the waiting thread a chance to acquire the mutex immediately, before the notifying thread reacquires the lock.

You could add `std::this_thread::yield()` calls between iterations, to give other threads a chance to acquire the lock. However, this is less than ideal --- any code where you have to explicitly do something to mess with the scheduler is a target for rewriting.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the spurious wakeups! But I already had the unlock before the notify and it made absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the sleep with:

```
std::this_thread::yield();
```

This will give the other thread a chance to take the lock.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield

Comment: Reading the specification this would be exactly what I need, but somehow it doesn't work while it does with the sleep. Also I think it wouldn't make a real difference because a function call (no matter which) takes longer than the actual sleep. But then it will never be possible to make it more efficient the way it is. Something which guarantees that another waiting thread gets the lock prior to the same would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a condition variable:

```
long s[2] = {1234,1234}; // instead of a single value


void func1() {
    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck1(m1);
        int n1(n);
        long s1(s[0]);
        long s2(s[1]);
        lck1.unlock();

        int n2 = n1 + 1;
// ...rest of func1 is unchanged...


void func2() {
    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck1(m1);
        n++;
        // compute s[0]
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((n*n)/3));
        n++;
        // compute s[1]
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((n*n)/3));

        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested and it has very weird behaviour. Sometimes it prints only one line (probably never coming back to func1) or it just prints the same first line endlessly without change (so probably never coming back to func2). Furthermore it doubles the needed storage which I need to keep an eye on too to not run onto swap too fast which is simply slower.